# Elegant geometric distribution function for percentages (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I need a random number for many projects. For example, consider a video game in which the character finds a bag of gold that is partially empty. To set the percentage of gold in the bag, I would often use `Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 0.5)`. Upon reading about geometric distribution, I sought to make a geometric distribution random percentage generator. After reading dozens of articles, I cobbled together this function:

```
function geoDistPercent() {
    var rand = Math.random();
    var prob = ???;
    var rate = -Math.log(1 - prob);
    var expr = -Math.log(rand)/rate;
    return Math.floor(min + expr);
}
```

I have tried various numbers for `prob = ???`, but I am unable to find a way to add a maximum limit. I have tried many attempts at finding equations, to no avail. Pleas help!

**UPDATE:** I have just learned that geometric distribution has no maximum. I need a way to add one, so that results like "112%" are not generated. This could be done by adding a `while` loop and some control flow. It is the `prob = ???` issue that I need help with.

Comment: A geometric distribution has no maximum.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I realized that a few minutes ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after reviewing lots of articles and some other posts on SE, I cobbled together this solution:

```
function geoDist(min, max, prob) {
    var q = 0;
    var p = Math.pow(prob, 1 / (max - min));
    while (true) {
        q = Math.ceil(Math.log(1-Math.random()) / Math.log(p)) + (min - 1);
        if (q <= max) {
            return q;
        }
    }
}
```

It takes three parameters: `min` and `max`, as well as `prob`: the probability of getting `max` in one try. For generating percentages, `geoDist(0,100,0.002)` works exceptionally well. Thanks @NathanMerrill and @Bergi for providing helpful information

Comment: Realized shortly after this that `Math.random() ** 2` works just as well...

Comment: Needed a function for this thank you!